# how to auto change date in dropdown menu with AJAX or javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, date, drop-down-menu

first of all I'm trying to have the dropdown menu send input value to the `form.php` and the dropdown menu is on the `index.php`

I have this drop down menu

```
<select name="date" id="date" style="width:100px;" onchange="availablePeriodOfDay(this)">
    <option value="2011-08-21" >2011-08-21</option>
    <option value="2011-08-20" >2011-08-20</option>
    <option value="2011-08-19" >2011-08-19</option>
    <option value="2011-08-18" >2011-08-18</option>
    <option value="2011-08-17" >2011-08-17</option>
    <option value="2011-08-16" >2011-08-16</option>
    <option value="2011-08-15" >2011-08-15</option>
    <option value="2011-08-14" >2011-08-14</option>
</select>
```

this one is going back 8 days from the current day but if I want it to change the date automatic if the date changed to tomorrow `2011-08-22` and make the rest also change everytime automatically

will that be possible to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to do there is generate it in PHP when the page is loaded - do you want something like this?

```
<?php

  $numDaysToShow = 8;
  $_1day = 60 * 60 * 24; // 1 day in seconds (=86400)
  $start = time();
  $end = $start - ($_1day * $numDaysToShow); // 8 days ago
  $theSelect = "<select name=\"date\" id=\"date\" style=\"width:100px;\" onchange=\"availablePeriodOfDay(this)\">";
  for ($i = $start; $i > $end; $i -= $_1day) $theSelect .= "\n  <option value=\"".date('Ymd',$i)."\">".date('Y-m-d',$i)."</option>";
  $theSelect .= "\n</select>";

  print($theSelect);

?>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want thank you so much you are great!!! 

Can I ask you one more thing what if I want the value to be send to the form.php without the dash?? " - " ??

Comment: So you mean the data sent would be like `20110821` instead of `2011-08-21`?

Comment: that is correct because I'm trying to send data for time and date to the input of the link like this 

http://mydomain.com:$channel-$date-$time.mp4

and the result should be like this

http://mydomain.com:ch41-20110822-00.mp4

Comment: I have edited the code above so it does what you want - all that is needed is to remove the dashes from the format string passed to the first call of `date()`. I have also added another variable `$numDaysToShow` that you can change if you decide you want more/less than 8 days.

Comment: I don't know if you are around but I just have one more question when I asked you if I can take off the dash that was perfectly done but if I want to echo with php

example "Today is $_POST(DATE) but I want the echo to show the dash like 2011-08-22 and without effecting the data send like 20110822

will that be any possible way to do so?

Comment: Yes, you can do this: `echo 'Today is '.substr($_POST['date'],0,4).'-'.substr($_POST['date'],4,2).'-'.substr($_POST['date'],6,2);`

Comment: I have place the code and isn't display don't know why really sorry for being noobie here

Comment: @Ali let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2718/discussion-between-daverandom-and-ali)

Comment: I don't know if you are around here sorry to disturbing you here again

Comment: can we discuss for minute in the same chat?